# libreoffice cannot find -lstdc++

Tags: linux, crash, libreoffice, libraries, c++

when I try to open the application LibreOffice on linux it shows the Openning Logo then crashes and prints this lines :

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lstdc++ 
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation) soffice.bin: common.c:108: llvm_codegen: Assertion `error == 0'failed.
```

I don't know how to proceed.Does anyone know how to fix it?Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to run this in the terminal:

> sudo apt-get install libstdc++

or

> sudo apt-get update
>
> sudo apt-get install build-essential
>
> sudo apt-get install aptitude
>
> sudo apt-get install libstdc++6